# Проблема с вводом из консоли

Tags: c++

Только учусь с++. Написал простенькую программу, с циклом while. В начале вводится любое число. Если ввести более-менее маленькое всё работет, но когда я ввожу например 10000000000000000000, то программа не реагирует на нажатия в следуюшем вводе. Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // для system
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int money;
    int k2;
    cin >> money;
    cin >> k2;
    int start_time = clock();
    int money_now = 1;
    while (money_now * k2 <= money) {
        money_now++;
    }
    cout << money_now;
    int end_time = clock();
    int search_time = end_time - start_time;
    cout << "Программа работала: " << search_time;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не хочу вас расстраивать, но 10000000000000000000 никак не поместится в `int`...

Answer (score 4):

Не хочу вас расстраивать, но 10000000000000000000 никак не поместится в `int`...

В результате - у вас ввод неверный (просто не выполненный), приводит к тому, что в `money` и `k2` оказываются непрочитанными, там лежит что угодно... Ну, и соответственно, если, скажем, в `k2`оказывается отрицательное значение - такой цикл может работать ну очень долго :)

Проверьте - у вас уже после первого ввода `cin.good()` даст `false` - типа такого вставьте:

```
cin >> money;
cout << cin.good() << endl;
cin >> k2;
cout << cin.good() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что 10000000000000 слишком большое число для int. Нужно было либо сменить тип перемнной либо умеьшить воодимое число.
[Это было полезно](http://cppstudio.com/post/271/)